# Fix date when print sheet in excel 2016

Tags: excel, date, excel-2016

I have a sheet with a cell that must to show the printed day.

For example, the cell W1, in the sheet 01 will be printed today at night and at moment that print it, that cell must to show the current day.

It has to be automatically when the sheet is printed.

If tomorrow I open the workbook, in that sheet it has to view the day of printed and not **NOW()**

It could be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This will either have to be manual or done with VBA. `NOW()` and others like it will continuously update

Comment: @urdearboy yes... I think that it could be use some macro for this. With VBA is it possible? thanks

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

Open Macro and on the ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
   For Each wk In Worksheets
       wk.Range("W1").Value = Now()
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to define wk here